# How to get wikipedia page in multi languages?

Tags: api, wikipedia

How can I get the same wikipedia page in another language.

For example I want to get this page in Japanese, 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud

result is

[http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/雲](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%B2)
or only the title 雲

Is it possible to use wikipedia API or any other APIs to do this?

Thank You

Comment: I'd think that author wants to access Wikipedia information from software he/she develops so it is related to programming.

Comment: I don't see why this should be closed; the question is both valid and on-topic.

Comment: I am trying to ask about API.. but I'm sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lang links property of MediaWiki [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-_Properties#langlinks_.2F_ll) is probably what you want.  Fetching other languages for your cloud example would look like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Cloud&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500).